# I am looking for CANON PIXMA MP250

Tags: printing, canon

I am looking for drivers for a CANON PIXMA MP250 for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Anyone knows how to install one?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Canon Printer Driver project page on Launchpad. The packages have not been upgraded for precise yet.

You should be able to install the oneiric files though, as I doubt the dependencies have changed that much.

Go [here](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon/+files/scangearmp-mp250series_1.70-1ubuntu10_i386.deb) for the 32-bit or [here](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon/+files/scangearmp-mp250series_1.70-1ubuntu10_amd64.deb) for the 64-bit drivers.

This will allow for you save the files to your local machine. Once you've saved them you can right click and install the deb file, using a method you prefer.

I will show you the command line method if you prefer. You will need to pull them down the drivers by issuing the following command (In this example I have chosen to use give the commands to pull down the 32-bit drivers, and install them):

```
wget http://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon/+files/scangearmp-mp250series_1.70-1ubuntu10_i386.deb
```

Then install by typing:

```
sudo dpkg -i scangearmp-mp250series_1.70-1ubuntu10_i386.deb
```

Comment: Thanks, itnet7. Your answer did not solve my problem, but it did put me on the track for a solution. Michael Gruz has another PPA on Launchpad which does have drivers for Precise. It is called "Canon printer driver daily".

Comment: Cool, I was going to say just add his ppa, but I thought based on you mentioning that model#, that could have been the one you needed. Either way glad it worked out for you!!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me at ubuntu 12.04 x64 - canon MP250:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-common
```

Restart.

[cnijfilter-common-3.60 - details](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-trunk/+packages)